# How to get custom css style by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get style by writing classes.

- If i write a class name **"m-t-9"** then it will add **margin-top: 9px;**.
- If i write **"m-t-13"** then it will add **margin-top: 13px;**
- If I write **"m-t-m-12** then it will add **margin-top: -12px;** for me.

I want this kind of actions through pure **JavaScript (Not jQuery)**. I tried a lot but failed. Can any one please let me know the js code for this?

Comment: You can create css classnames like you have above and give them the styles you want added. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class

Comment: Bootstrap has some classes that seem to act like this, you could see how it does it.

Comment: @mkaatman That would require creating dozens of classes, for every possible margin-top, margin-bottom, margin-left, and margin-right value.

Comment: VS code can do shortcuts like this that expand out.

Comment: But Bootstrap may simply have a limited set of classes like this, and list them all in its .css files.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to do dynamic classes using [`less`](https://lesscss.org/)

Comment: @Barmar Less will compile to regular CSS, so OP will need to basically create `for` loops to create the CSS necessary. Not a big deal, but if they want JS to do this, they should show what was tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with an obj to define your rules for property, pos and unit. Then you run two functions, one that formats the style and the other that gathers the classes.

**NOTE:** This method uses the inline css in HTML to style elements with a parsed string set in the class attribute of elements.

The first function would get the class as a string and then using `el.substring`, decontruct it into its parts: **prop** **pos** and **unit**. We match the classObjs keys with the deconstructed parts of our passed in class string. Then we set the *parts* to the keys values.

prop:
`m` => `margin`
`p` => `padding`

pos:

- `l` => `left`
- `r` => `right`
- `t` => `top`
- `b` => `bottom`
- `n` => `''`

Unit: `px`

note: `n` would basically be something like: `padding: 20px;` no position, so: `p-n-20`

The second function will take the element/s we pass into it and set their respective styles to that of the class string we have in their class attribute using a regex match. I use two regex/s one for *positive* units and the other for *negative* units. So our potential classes would look like: `m-l-30` => `margin-left: 30px;` or `p-t-10` => `padding-top: 10px;` or `m-b--20` => `margin-bottom: -20px;` or `p-n-30` => `padding: 30px;`. Then the function gets the *current inline style* if present and then appends the *new parsed style* to the *current style* and sets the *elements inline style* to the concatonated string.

```js
//get all elements inside .main
const test = document.querySelectorAll('.main *')

const classObj = {
  property: {
    m: "margin",
    p: "padding"
  },
  position: {
    t: "-top",
    b: "-bottom",
    l: "-left",
    r: "-right",
    n: ""
  },
  unit: "px"
}

function setStyleFromClass(str) {
  let styledClass = '';
  const prop = str.substring(0,1),
    pos = str.substring(2,3),
    unit = str.substring(4,str.length)
    
  for (keys in classObj) {
    if (typeof classObj[keys] === 'object') {
      if (prop in classObj[keys]) {
        styledClass += classObj[keys][prop]
      }
      if (pos in classObj[keys]) {
        styledClass += `${classObj[keys][pos]}:`
      }
    } else {
      styledClass += `${unit}px;`
    }

  }
  return styledClass;
}

function getEls(el) {
  const regex = /([m|p]{1}[\-]{1}[t|b|l|r|n]{1}[\-][0-9]+)/g
  if (el.length > 1) {
    // node list
    let classes = ''
    el.forEach(tag => {
      const classes = tag.getAttribute('class')
      let classArr = classes.split(' ')
      classArr.forEach(cls => {
        if(cls.match(regex)) {
          let style = setStyleFromClass(cls)
          let cur = tag.getAttribute('style')
          cur ?
            tag.setAttribute('style', `${cur} ${style}`) :
            tag.setAttribute('style', `${style}`)
        }
        if(cls.match(/([m|p]{1}[\-]{1}[t|b|l|r|n]{1}[\-][\-][0-9]+)/gm)) {
          let style = setStyleFromClass(cls)
          let cur = tag.getAttribute('style')
          cur ?
            tag.setAttribute('style', `${cur} ${style}`) :
            tag.setAttribute('style', `${style}`)
        }
      })
    })
  }
}

getEls(test)
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.redbg {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="test red m-t-50 p-l-50">test div element -> m-t-150 margin-top: 150</div>
  <p class="test redbg m-b--10 p-n-20">test p element has a negative margin-bottom of 10px, should push next element up into border-box</p>
  <div id="testId" class="p-l-200">test element with padding right 200px</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const options = {
  matchRegex: new RegExp('[m][-][t|l|b|r][-][0-9]+'),
  'm-t': {
    styleName: 'margin-top',
    affix: 'px',
    prefix: ''
  },
  'm-l': {
    styleName: 'margin-left',
    affix: 'px',
    prefix: ''
  },
  'm-b': {
    styleName: 'margin-bottom',
    affix: 'px',
    prefix: ''
  },
  'm-r': {
    styleName: 'margin-right',
    affix: 'px',
    prefix: ''
  }
}
document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach((e) => {
  e.classList.forEach((classname) => {
    if (options.matchRegex.test(classname)) {
      const li = classname.lastIndexOf('-');
      const type = classname.substring(0, li);
      const value = classname.substring(li + 1);
      const details = options[type];
      e.style[details.styleName] = details.prefix + value + details.affix;
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="m-t-50 m-b-50">
  Margin Top 50, Margin Bottom 50
</div>
<div class="m-t-10 m-l-20">
  Margin Top 10, Margin Left 20
</div>
```